# Error con volley

Tags: android, android-volley

lo que pasa es que al ejecutar desde el android este codigo [image: este es el codigo que ejecuto desde el android]

lo que pasa es que al ejecutarlo me genera el siguiente mensaje de error

[image: este error]

pero si ejecuto en el navegador le mando los datos correspondientes me funciona

este es el código php [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] la verdad no veo el porque. tengo otro actividad y este funciona correctamente

Comment: Agrega texto en lugar de imagenes del código, saludos!

Comment: Imprime el resultado de tu respuesta y veras que no es un json por esa razón marca ese error.

Answer (score 1):

El error que obtienes:

> org.json.JSONException: Value < br of type java.lang.String cannot be
>   converted to JSONObject

**es debido a que la repuesta que obtienes y  tratas de parsear como JSON en realidad no es una estructura JSON.**

Asegura que la respuesta que obtengas de la petición sea en realidad una estructura json.

Comment: es que me parece extraño tengo un login algo similar y este si funciona, pero este no

Comment: Imprime la respuesta que se "parseara" y saldrás de dudas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorgesys, ya pude "arreglar el problema " lo que pasaba era con los tipos de datos que ingresaba. Saludos y muchas gracias por su tiempo !!

Comment: Me imagino enviabas datos incorrectos y el servicio regresaba un mensaje de error que en realidad no era un json, saludos.

Comment: Exactamente, el problema radicaba en el campo que en la base de datos lo tengo como un Boolean, pero yo  supuesta mente lo modifique para poder recibir otro dato pero, por lo que vi el cambio no lo tomo, le envié un boolean y pumm me ingreso,  Saludos